# Container not centered in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Somehow my container is not centered. I tried diffrent ways to center like: i used in this code example `container` then add `alignment:`. I also tried to change `container` to `center`. Aswel as wrapping the hole `column` in a `center`. So far it didn't work the way i want it to. The top 2 rows from the Listview are not centered correctly. The bottom 2 rows are centered correctly.  Thanks in advance

This is what my app looks like:

[image]

Flutter code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Menu'),
          backgroundColor:Colors.deepOrange
      ),
      body: machineList == null || machineList.isEmpty
          ? const Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         )
        : SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget> [
            Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: machineList == null ? 0  : machineList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Machinepage(widget.klant)),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.person_add, size: 50,color: Colors.white,),
                            title: Text(machineList[index].serienummer.toString(), style: const TextStyle(color:Colors.white,fontSize:20),),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }, //itemBuilder
                  ),
                ]
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget> [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 10.0, top:15.0, bottom: 12.0),
                      child: const Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Icon(Icons.filter_1_rounded, size: 50,color: Colors.white,),
                      )
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(

                  flex: 8,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 4.0),
                    child: Text(machineList[0].serienummer.toString(),style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white,fontSize:20),),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(), // this is the same row as the row above
          ]
          )
      ),
      drawer: Drawer();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with it's not centered. How do you expect it to look?

Comment: Can you include an where do you like to put those

Comment: I want the top 2 rows with the person+ icon the same as the 2 rows with the [1] and [2]

Comment: Then make them in the same way? the top ones are ListTiles, the bottom ones Rows

Comment: @Ivo Somehow in my head this didn't seem to be logic. but so far it seems to work.

Comment: just replace the ListTile with row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the flex control the width on row, While it is having different flex, it is take its portion. And to align text use `textAlign`. And to have the same view, replace ListTile with row and follow the same widget structure

You can do it

```dart
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 5,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.person_add,
                size: 50,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: Text(
                machineList[index],
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )),
  );
},
```

```dart
class GART extends StatefulWidget {
  GART({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GART> createState() => _GARTState();
}

class _GARTState extends State<GART> {
  var machineList = ["A", "B"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: machineList == null ? 0 : machineList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 5,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.person_add,
                                size: 50,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 8,
                              child: Text(
                                machineList[index],
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  );
                }, //itemBuilder
              ),
            ],
          ),
          itemBuilder(),
          // Row(), // this is the same row as the row above
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Row itemBuilder() {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 40.0, right: 10.0, top: 15.0, bottom: 12.0),
              child: const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.filter_1_rounded,
                  size: 50,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 8,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 4.0),
            child: Text(
              machineList[0],
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```